# Where are the ampersand and vertical bar characters used in Python?

Tags: python, short-circuiting

In the [Wikipedia page describing short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), `&` and `|` are listed as eager operators in Python. What does this mean and when are they used in the language?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The wikipedia page is wrong, I've corrected it. `|` and `&` are not boolean operators, even though they *are* eager operators, which just means that they are not short circuit operators. As you probably know, here's how the python `and` and `or` operators work:

```
>>> def talk(x):
...     print "Evaluating: ", bool(x)
...     return x
... 
>>> talk(1 == 1) or talk(2 == 1)   # 2 == 1 is not evaluated
Evaluating:  True
True
>>> talk(1 == 1) and talk(2 == 1)
Evaluating:  True
Evaluating:  False
False
>>> talk(1 == 2) and talk(1 == 3)  # 1 == 3 is not evaluated
Evaluating:  False
False
```

As far as I know, python has no eager boolean operators, they would have to be explicitly coded, for instance like this:

```
>>> def eager_or(a, b):
...    return a or b
...
>>> eager_or(talk(1 == 1), talk(2 == 1))
Evaluating:  True
Evaluating:  False
True
```

Now `a` and `b` are automatically evaluated when the function is called, even though `or` still short circuits.

As for the usage of `|` and `&`, when used with numbers, they are binary operators:

```
>>> bin(0b11110000 & 0b10101010)
'0b10100000'
>>> bin(0b11110000 | 0b10101010)
'0b11111010'
```

You're most likely to use `|` this way with python bindings to libraries that uses flags, like wxWidgets:

```
>>> frame = wx.Frame(title="My Frame", style=wx.MAXIMIZE | wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
>>> bin(wx.MAXIMIZE)
'0b10000000000000'
>>> bin(wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
'0b1000000000000000'
>>> bin(wx.MAXIMIZE | wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
'0b1010000000000000'
```

When used with sets, they do the *intersection* and *union* operations, respectively:

```
>>> set("abcd") & set("cdef")
set(['c', 'd'])
>>> set("abcd") | set("cdef")
set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'd', 'f'])
```

Comment: They're also used in `pandas` for complex query strings on data frames, such as `df[ (df['Age'] > 40) & (df['Weight'] < 100)]`.

Comment: @cod3monk3y I just saw this usage in NumPy too and was confused at first, but I guess there's no other simple way to combine boolean arrays for indexing.

Comment: You're absolutely right but chose a bad example ;) Python treats `bool` class values as integers in bitwise operations (`0 == False` and `1 == True` are both true) so your example will work with `&` and `|`  acting like eager logical operators.

Comment: `&` and `|` do indeed work with `True` and `False`, and not just implicitly because they're 0 and 1: for example, `True | False` is `True`, not 1.

Comment: Since [python 3.9](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#dict) `|` is now finally used for union of dictionaries as well: 
`{'a': 1, 'b': 2} | {'c': 3, 'b': 4}` becomes `{'a': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 3}`. Sadly other set operators have yet to be added to dict as of yet.

Answer (score 35):

Something missing from the other answers here is that `&` and `|` don't have any universal meaning in Python; their meaning depends on the operands' types, using the magic `__and__` and `__or__` methods. Since these are methods, the operands are both evaluated (i.e. without short-circuiting) before being passed as arguments.

On `bool` values they are logical "and" and logical "or":

```py
>>> True & False
False
>>> True | False
True
>>> bool.__and__(True, False)
False
>>> bool.__or__(True, False)
True
```

On `int` values they are bitwise "and" and bitwise "or":

```py
>>> bin(0b1100 & 0b1010)
'0b1000'
>>> bin(0b1100 | 0b1010)
'0b1110'
>>> bin(int.__and__(0b1100, 0b1010))
'0b1000'
>>> bin(int.__or__(0b1100, 0b1010))
'0b1110'
```

On sets, they are intersection and union:

```py
>>> {1, 2} & {1, 3}
{1}
>>> {1, 2} | {1, 3}
{1, 2, 3}
>>> set.__and__({1, 2}, {1, 3})
{1}
>>> set.__or__({1, 2}, {1, 3})
{1, 2, 3}
```

A couple of extra notes:

- The `__and__` and `__or__` methods are always looked up on the class, not on the instance. So if you assign `obj.__and__ = lambda x, y: ...` then it's still `obj.__class__.__and__` that's invoked.
- The `__rand__` and `__ror__` methods on the class will take priority, if they are defined.

See the [Python language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) for more details.

Answer (score 11):

It means the left operand and the right operand are always evaluated. `&` is the bitwise AND operator and `|` is the bitwise OR operator.

Comment: so does eager mean they don't use short-circuit evaluation like the logical operators?

Comment: @Keoki Zee: yes. Eager is the opposite of [lazy](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Lazy_evaluation).

Comment: @Keoki - Yes, they don't short-circuit. If you think of them as arithmetic operators like `+` or `-`, instead of boolean operators, then you'll realise that talking about "short-circuiting" doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 5):

& ----> Used to AND bitwise i.e. bit by bit

similarly,

| ---> used to OR bitwise

Whenevr you find any python problem, try to use python.org, its helpful

Comment: @down voter : Please write the comment for your down voting, Is this wrong

Comment: not a helpful comment. have you tried looking for documentation using keywords '&' and '|'? Also, you didn't answer the question: "What does this mean and when are they used in the language?"

Comment: @warvariuc, whats hard about reading the documentation? Go to docs.python.org, click on 'General Index', this gives you choices 'Symbols', '_', 'A', 'B', etc. Click on Symbols and you'll find '&' right near the top (but admittedly not '|'). Click on the '&' entry and it tells you all about both. Failing that, interactive prompt and type `help('&')` or `help('|')` for a useful table of operators.

Comment: if you edit your answer i will be able to cancel my down-vote. what about adding these hints how to find the help on these operators?

Comment: i downvoted you because in my opinion you didn't answer the question "What does this mean", but i guess the topic starter didn't use the right word (should he have used "these"?).

Comment: I tried python.org first and was unable to find "|".  This is due to my own ignorance. As evidenced by my own experience, by the time someone posts asking what "|" is I think that it is reasonable to assume that they might not know how to find '|' in the documentation. "Look in the documentation" is not an answer, but "Look in the documentation: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#index-19" is.