# function return none instead of return number

Tags: python, if-statement

I create a function that compare with x and y variable. Inside the function has a lots of nested elif to compare the x and y then return integer. The problem is right now, when it runs at the certain elif statement, it didn't execute the statement although the statement is correct.

```
def convertTo(self, x, y):
    if( x == 0 & y == 0):
        return 0
    if( x == 0 & y == 1):
        return 1
    if( x == 0 & y == 2):
        return 2
    if( x == 0 & y == 3):
        return 3
    if( x == 1 & y == 0): 
        return 4 # Didn't return this line even though x = 1 and y = 0
    else
        return None

def main():
    self.convertTo(0,0)
    self.convertTo(0,1)
    self.convertTo(0,2)
    self.convertTo(0,3)
    self.convertTo(1,0) # return None? Why?
```

Comment: Have you tried `and` instead of `&`?

Comment: @tobias_k Operator precedence is different.

Comment: Short circuit? maybe? Just a question... Anyways, how do we know what's returned? The code doesn't output anything

Comment: Note that your `if/else` structure is odd. It should be a series of `if/elif/else`. But you could also just drop the `else: return None` entirely, as that's the default anyway.

Comment: I think the order of operations executes the bitwise operator before the comparision

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488928/where-are-the-ampersand-and-vertical-bar-characters-used-in-python

Comment: @cricket_007 Nope I didn't tried that. Seems work. Can I know why?

Comment: Python also doesn't need `()` in `if` statements.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're performing a chained equality comparison which is not doing what you think it does. The bitwise `&` is performed first as it has a higher priority than `==`.

Replace:

```
x == 1 & y == 0
# 1 == 1 & 0 == 0
# 1 == 0 == 0  False!
```

With:

```
x == 1 and y == 0
```

---

See: [Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Comment: This, basically it's parsed as `x == (1 & y) == 0`.

Comment: AKA PEMDAS for adults!

Answer (score 1):

In Python, "&" and "and" do two different things.  "and" is what you should be using, "&" is a binary operator.

if
a = 0011 1100

and

b = 0000 1101

then

a&b = 0000 1100

See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm

Comment: But that by itself isn't the entire explanation.

Comment: But that does not explain why it fails in this case, after all `True & True` would still be true. The critical point is indeed operator precedence.

Answer (score 0):

You should use and instead of &, as & is a bitwise and.

Chaining multiple conditions in Python is generally done with an if-elif-else statement like below:

```
if a and b:
   # a and b both was true
elif a and not b:
   # a was true, but b wasn't
else:
   # none of the conditions matched
```

In your code, if it wasn't for the return statement in each if, and the fact that you are checking the same two variables, it would be possible for two if statements to evaluate to true.

```
if a:
   # this will run if a was true
if b:
   # regardless of a this will run if b was true
else:
   # regardless of a this will only run if b was false
```

Also, take a look at this: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html