# Pandas logical operator & does not work but 'and' works

Tags: python, pandas

I am having problem with logical operators in pandas.
If I try :

```
list1=['x','y']
if st1=='A' & str2 not in list1: #do stuff
```

I get:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'bool'", u'occurred at index 0
```

But this works: Why?

```
if st1=='A' and str2 not in list1: #do stuff
```

All I did was change & to and.

Comment: You probably want `st1 == 'A' not the `=`

Comment: Sorry that is what i did...error still persists.

Answer (score 3):

`&` and `and` are not the same thing in Python - `&` is a bitwise operator, `and` is a logical operator. See previous answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646463/difference-between-and-boolean-vs-bitwise-in-python-why-difference-i) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488928/where-are-the-ampersand-and-vertical-bar-characters-used-in-python/6490106), and Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) on bitwise operations.

In pandas you can use `&` for logical operations when selecting subsets of DataFrames, e.g.:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"col1":[1,2,3], "col2":[2,3,4]})
df[(df["col1"]>1) & (df["col2"]<4)] # Selects second row based on boolean criteria
```