# Is there a more elegant way of counting combinations of booleans from 2 arrays?

Tags: python, math, conditional-statements

I tried to word the question as simply as possible but I'm new to Python and very bad at logic so I'm having a bit of trouble. Basically I want to know if there's a cleaner way to count confusion matrices of two 1D arrays of booleans.

Here's an example:

```
arr1 = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
arr2 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
tp = fp = tn = fn = 0

for i,p in enumerate(arr1):

    a = arr2[i]

    if  p &  a: tp += 1
    if  p & ~a: fp += 1
    if ~p & ~a: tn += 1
    if ~p &  a: fn += 1
    # This was pointed out to be incorrect (see Mozway's answer below)
```

I tried this but it just adds more lines and looks arguably worse:

```
if p == o:
    if p: tp += 1
    else: tn += 1
else:
    if p: fp += 1
    else: fn += 1
```

I then tried adding nested conditional expressions (I believe these are Python's version of ternary operators?) but this disgusting monstrosity doesn't even compile:

```
(tp += 1 if a else fp += 1) if p else (tn += 1 if ~a else fn += 1)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: Sorry I should have clarified, the result I want is this:

Adding *print(tp, fp, tn, fn)* would give *1, 2, 2, 1*. Simply counting the combinations of each of the booleans in the arrays.

Comment: What exactly you want? Can you tell us what you expecting from your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(zip(arr1, arr2))

tp = c[1,1]
fp = c[1,0]
tn = c[0,0]
fn = c[0,1]

print(tp, fp, tn, fn)
```

output: `(1, 2, 2, 1)`

counter:

```
print(c)
# Counter({(0, 1): 1, (0, 0): 2, (1, 0): 2, (1, 1): 1})
```

###### alternative way to index the counter:

```
ids = {'tp': (1,1), 'fp': (1,0), 'tn': (0,0), 'fn': (0,1)}

c[ids['tp']]
# 1
```

###### why your first approach failed

`bool(~1)` is `True` (`~1` is `-2`), thus giving incorrect counts. `~` is used as `not` in a vectorial setup (e.g. with numpy), but not in pure python. You can use `1-x` (not `~x`) to invert an "integer as boolean" (`1-0` -> `1` ; `1-1` -> `0`).

References on the [`~`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305199/the-tilde-operator-in-python) and [`&`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488928/where-are-the-ampersand-and-vertical-bar-characters-used-in-python) operators in pure python (you should use `not` and `and`). Their meaning is different in `numpy`.